# Undefined property error

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-modules, drupal-views

Hi, I have installed cloud zoom model, but it's not working properly. It gives the following error message:

```
Undefined property: stdClass::$cz_verion in cloud_zoom_library() (line 38 of /home/drupalpro/websites/tragigrupp.dev/profiles/commerce_kickstart/modules/contrib/cloud_zoom/cloud_zoom.module
```

I've also installed all related jQuery libraries in the libraries folder. Also, when I try in `localhost` server, it works properly, but not in my main server (both servers having the same drupal7 version and theme).

Thank you!

Comment: Which Drupal version are you using? You have drupal-6 and drupal-7 tags together!

Comment: @TheodorosPloumis drupal7 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue has been solved in Drupal.org for the cloud_zoom module [Zoom no longer working after update & error](https://drupal.org/node/1815186)! There is also a related issue on COmmerce_Kickstart: [Undefined property: stdClass::$cz_verion](https://drupal.org/node/1821962)

Comment: Thank you sir @TheodorosPloumis .know error message is not appearing in screen. but zoom still not working .